# I got failed when flask.py pythonanywhere

Tags: flask

I got this error below I try flask.py this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rekcah-pavi/website/main/flask.py
Can someone help me fix it?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/bin/pythonanywhere_runner.py",
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/bin/pythonanywhere_runner.py",
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/bin/pythonanywhere_runner.py",
line 35, in _pa_run
globals().update(new_variables)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callab
le

I try fix error after flask.py

Comment: See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/

Comment: Please don't post links your code. Instead provide a [mre] and include the relevant code as text in your question.